# Running PEP8 checks from Python

Tags: python, pep8

I can not run PEP8 checks from a Python script.

I don't want explicitly run pep8.exe, because I want to automate this checks, and pep8 executable can lay in different places on different platforms.

Answer (score 7):

[PEP8 advanced usage](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html) covers using pep8 inside Python script.

Quoting an example:

```
import unittest
import pep8


class TestCodeFormat(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_pep8_conformance(self):
        """Test that we conform to PEP8."""
        pep8style = pep8.StyleGuide(quiet=True)
        result = pep8style.check_files(['file1.py', 'file2.py'])
        self.assertEqual(result.total_errors, 0,
                         "Found code style errors (and warnings).")
```

Comment: I've seen it. But I still have questions.
1) How to print all found violations?
2) How to check all Python files in a directory?

Comment: 1) remove quiet=True.
2) Use os.walk to build a list of all python files in a dir and pass that in to check_files().